# Android SimpleCursorAdapter to CursorAdapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I'm using `SimpleCursorAdapter` to manage my query to the database and then showing the results in a `ListView`.

Here is my code:

```
database.open();
ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
Cursor c = database.getData();
startManagingCursor(c);


String[] from = new String[]{Database._GROUP_NAME};
int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, query, from, to);

listContent.setAdapter(adapter);

database.close();
```

Although, at first look, it it working as expected, I believe that this should NOT be the way to proceed since there is `CursorAdapter`.

I know that this is a noob question but since just started now programming in Android I still don't know much.

How can I pass this from using `SimpleCursorAdapter` to `CursorAdapter`? 
Already searched on internet but wasn't able to understand how this can be done.

Not asking code just some directions.

Thanks

favolas

**UPDATE FOLLOWING mainu COMMENT**

```
database.open();
ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
Cursor c = database.getData();
MyAdapt cursorAdapter = new MyAdapt(this, query);


listContent.setAdapter(adapter);

database.close();
```

MyAdapt class:

```
public class MyAdapt extends CursorAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyAdapt(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView groupName = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        groupName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(Database._GROUP_NAME)));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = mInflater.inflate(
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way?

favolas

Comment: create a class SimpleCursorAdapter which will extends a CursorAdapter. And you will get some by default overRideed methods. UU will get cleared then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleCursorAdapter is the simplest form of Adapter you can use for a custom adapter.
You should use SimpleCursorAdapter only, by when you dont need any customization.